# Scipy sparse matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have this example of matrix by matrix multiplication using numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
c = np.array([0,1,2])
m * c
array([[ 0,  2,  6],
       [ 0,  5, 12],
       [ 0,  8, 18]])
```

How can i do the same thing if m is scipy sparse CSR matrix? This gives dimension mismatch:

```
sp.sparse.csr_matrix(m)*sp.sparse.csr_matrix(c)
```

Comment: `*` multiplication is element by element with arrays, but the matrix product with sparse matrices.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can call the `multiply` method of `csr_matrix` to do pointwise multiplication.

```
sparse.csr_matrix(m).multiply(sparse.csr_matrix(c)).todense()

# matrix([[ 0,  2,  6],
#         [ 0,  5, 12],
#         [ 0,  8, 18]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Nice.  Also, you can use the `.toarray()` if you are wanting a numpy `array` at the end.  I've been burned before when using `.todense()` which gives a numpy `matrix`.

Answer (score 2):

When `m` and `c` are numpy arrays, then `m * c` is not "matrix multiplication".  If you think it is then you may be making a mistake.  To get matrix multiplication use a matrix class, like numpy's `matrix` or the scipy.sparse matrix classes.

The reason you are getting the failure is that from the matrix point of view `c` is a 1x3 matrix:

```
c = np.matrix([0, 1, 2]) 
c.shape    # (1,3)

c = sp.csc_matrix([0, 1, 2])
c.shape    # (1,3)
```

If what you want is the matrix multiplication with `c` then you need to use the transpose.

```
c = np.matrix([0, 1, 2]).transpose()
c.shape    # (3,1)

m = np.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
m.shape    # (3,3)

m * c
# matrix([[ 8],
#         [17],
#         [26]])
```